# Force State changing of an Object only from Holder

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented-design

Suppose I have a Button class with a color attribute.
I also have a Canvas class which stores all Buttons.
Every time a color is being changed, some side action must take place (in this example, for simplicity, a counter will be raised).
As follows:

```
class Canvas {
    buttons: Array<Button>;
    counter: number = 0;
    foo() { this.counter++; }
    createButton {
        button = new Button();
        this.buttons.push(button);
        return button;
    }
    changeColor(button, color) {
        if (button.color == color)
            throw Error('This is the same color');
        button.color = color;
        foo(); // some effect that must be taked on color change;
    }
```

suppose buttons is private, so to add a new button to the canvas I must use the create method.

my question is, how can I force color changes to go trough changeColor function so that foo() gets called?

My main concern that a call will be made directly to the button:

```
button.color = 'red';
```

Which will not check if colors are same and not call foo();

A simple use case can be as following:

```
 canvas = new Canvas();
 button = canvas.createButton();
 color = 'red';
 canvas.changeColor(button, color); // I want this call only to be possible
 button.color = color; // but this call will also work
```

Comment: I would use the delegate pattern (or the observer pattern) to subscribe your canvas to receive notifications whenever any of the button's colour's changes. That way, it doesn't matter *how* the colour changes, just that it did.

Comment: ^ I agree. If you have control over the Button class, it's probably better and more flexible to let the user change the color via the button object; make it so that it is done through a setter, so that you can trigger a "change" event when the value is set. Then in createButton(), assign the canvas object as an observer/listener for the button's change event.
P.S. Add language tag, or edit the question to mention the language. Looks like TypeScript?

Answer (score 2):

This is feature envy.

The method changeColor should be on the button. The attribute color is part of a button. It is the button class' job to choose how color gets mutated. So you make color private to the button class, and then the only way the color changes is if you call the changeColor method.

Also note: It is the not the canvas' job to change the button's color. When you start to have other controls on the canvas, the number of methods you'll need to mutate those controls will also get enormous.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
return button;
```

Once you do that you've exposed the button. Anyone can call it directly.

Consider:

```
return new ButtonWrapper(this, button); //"this" representing canvas here
```

The button wrapper only permits changing button color though a method that also calls `canvas.foo()`. Since button was never exposed directly it can only be used in ways that follow the rules enforced by the wrapper.